# Wrap image to a cardView in android

Tags: android, image

So, I'm stuck with this for awhile,

I have this:

[image]

And I want something like this:
[image]

I don't get what I'm doing wrong in the code

The XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/CardTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:text="title" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:background="@color/stroke" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selectable_background_cardbank"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:padding="4dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out the answer

> android:adjustViewBounds="true"

in xml or

> imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true)

in Java.